# Drawing procedural 2D mesh in QML using shaders

Tags: c++, qt, qml, shader

I am generating complicated 2D mesh each frame, procedurally in C++ . Now I want to send this mesh to QML and add some good-looking postprocessing effects. I am aware that **ShaderEffect** supports only rectangle mesh as this is noted in documentation, but maybe there exist a workaround?